# NSAttributedString in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uipickerview

I'm having an `UIPickerView` in my ViewController. At first I wanted to use `attributedTitleForRow()`but I needed to make the font size smaller so I used `viewForRow...reusingView()`. As I didn't want to rewrite my code of `attributedTitleForRow()` I did the following:

```
let attributedString = pickerView(
    pickerView, attributedTitleForRow: row, 
        forComponent: component)
```

afterward I wanted to set the newView's property (an `UILabel`) `.attributedText = attributedString` I got an error from the line above: `pickerView(...) -> $T4 is not identical to` the rest wasn't displayed on my screen but usually the rest is only `UInt8`. I don't know where's the mistake. Any help would be great :]

The whole code in the `viewForRow()` function:

```
        var newView = view as? UILabel
        if newView == nil {
            newView = UILabel()
        }
        newView!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0)
        newView!.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        newView!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        newView!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6
        newView!.attributedText = (
            pickerView(pickerView, attributedTitleForRow: row, 
                forComponent: component))!
        newView!.textAlignment = .Center
        return newView!
```

The line calling the other pickerView function doesn't work - not only the way it is now in the code above

Comment: Big hint: when "the rest isn't displayed on my screen", look in the Issue Navigator.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't want to write the whole function I thought it was obvious

Comment: I'll do it better next time ;) Actually that doesn't work either. Even if I declare a variable first (inferred) which could, of course, be an Optional I still get the same warning

Comment: Okay, figured it out. See my new answer. Interesting challenge, thanks for the question. Sorry for all the red herrings earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the key line with `self` and all will be well:

```
newView!.attributedText = self.pickerView(
    pickerView, attributedTitleForRow:row, 
        forComponent:component)
```

This will allow your code to compile.

The reason is apparently that the `pickerView` in the method parameters is overshadowing your existing `pickerView...` method. Using `self` disambiguates.

(However, I'm concerned that this is never going to work because this code will never be called. If `attributedTitleForRow` is implemented, perhaps `viewForRow` is ignored? You will have to experiment and see whether my concern is justified.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution - that works perfectly! For your information, the `viewForRow()` isn't ignored, it kinda 'overrides' the other method, I've just tried it out.

Comment: I understand why you are trying to shortcut your way through this, so I'm happy if it works out. I was alerted that there might be a problem when I was in the UIPickerViewDelegate header, which says: "attributed title is favored if both methods are implemented". But now I think that means attributed title vs. _title_, so you should be fine.